# actionlib cancelGoal() error

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, actionlib, simpleactionclient, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Trying to cancelGoal() when no goal is
> running. You are incorrectly using
> SimpleActionClient

This is the error I get when I send a goal. I have subscribed to callbacks and I get a callback as soon as the goal goes active. So it surely does go active. Also, getStatus() fails similarly. But the state is described as LOST.

Please explain. I will provide additional information as necessary.

Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34407/actionlib-cancelgoal()-error/) by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am creating another SimpleActionClient local variable in a member function. The Class already has a member. So, I send the goal using the local variable, where as I try to cancel it using the Class variable. It can never work. Now, I am able to Pre-empt the goal. Sorry for the trouble. Problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2012-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0